# GREP command to find whole strings

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to get only a whole 4 digit number from my document using GREP command. But 4 digit number inside a 10 digit is also poping up.

Example :

```
grep '[0-9]\{4\}' testingthemail
```

should give only

```
" Year of passing : 2017 "
```

and not

```
"durairaj1696@gmail.com
9789879736
Year of passing : 2017
"
```

Comment: Use word boundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Ew '[0-9]{4}' testingthemail
```

-E  : Enables extended regexp so that the curly braces work

-w  : Select only whole words.

Answer (score 0):

> **Grep command to find a particular string inside the file**
>
> Grep command mostly used for searching string in the file. You can also search string inside file case sensitively.
>
> Check out command below
>
> ```
> grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' file | grep -v [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
> ```

For more information visit [grep command tutorial](https://linux4one.com/how-to-use-grep-command-in-linux-with-examples/)